# NativeScript Vue: What is the purpose of navigatingTo, navigatingFrom and other Page events?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am trying to understand how a Page event like `navigatedFrom` would be used.
Here is a base template:

```
<Page @navigatedFrom="navigatedFunc">
   <StackLayout></StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Say in my script sections, I had the function `navigatedFunc` listed in the methods sections:

```
navigatedFunc: function(args) {
   // what would I do here or check against? How would you check against a specific screen title you navigated from?
}
```

would it be used to check the specific view you navigated from?  Like can I do a conditional check in that function that would say if a user comes from the Account page, then do something?

Comment: If you want to run some script after user left the page (no longer visible on UI), then that's the place you write it.

Comment: What Manoj said. Providing an example, I usually fetch API data in `navigatingTo`, much like Vue `created` or `mounted`.

Comment: @TomG @Manok I was actually thinking exactly what @TomG said above ...Can't I do the same thing with `mounted()` and `created()`?  Do the Page events offer anything additional than those do?  Like with `navigatedFrom`, is there a way to check the module name you navigated from so if I wanted to do something specific _only_ when I navigated to Page X from Page Z and not from, for example, to Page X from Page Y ?

Comment: {N} page events are triggered by navigation, while Vue hooks by rendering, update, etc. This means little difference in forward navigation, but matters in backwards.
While {N} `$navigateBack` triggers page events, Vue `created`, `mounted` etc are not called, since the page is stored in the navigation stack.

Comment: ahh!  Didn't think of the fact that `mounted()` doesnt get called going backwards due to the nav. stack.  Perfect, thanks so much @TomG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those events are used if you want to run some code when a page appears or disappears. If you're familiar with native iOS apps, they're like the `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidDisappear` methods.

The `navigatingTo` event triggers when entering the page where it is registered.

The `navigatedTo` event triggers when when the navigation to the page has finished.

The `navigatingFrom` event triggers when a navigation away from the page starts.

The `navigatedFrom` event triggers when the navigation away from the page finished.

This image from the [NativeScript documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/page#page-events) might help you visualize the flow:

[image]